# Getting a total for current year - SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to get the total number of miles travelled this year using SQL in an access DB.
At the moment I'm trying the following query but its not working:

```
   SELECT 
      SUM(Mileage) 
   FROM 
      [Mileage-Expenses] 
   WHERE 
      YEAR(DatePurchased) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: *Not working* is not valid error message - not even in MS Access.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `WHERE` clause based on `YEAR(DatePurchased)` requires the db engine evaluate that expression for *every row* in the table.  You would get better performance by adding an index on `DatePurchased`, if you don't already have one, and then using a `WHERE` clause which allows the db engine to retrieve only the rows from the current year before computing `SUM(Mileage)`.

```
SELECT
    SUM(Mileage)
FROM 
    [Mileage-Expenses]
WHERE
        DatePurchased >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1)
    AND DatePurchased < DateSerial(Year(Date()) + 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not used MS Access for a long, long time, but as far as I remember it does not support `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you will need to use `DATE()` or `NOW()` instead:

```
   SELECT 
      SUM(Mileage) 
   FROM 
      [Mileage-Expenses] 
   WHERE 
      YEAR(DatePurchased) = YEAR(DATE())
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/use-current-date-and-time-in-calculations-HP001098479.aspx